# Create Custom Control: Errors in Extending ProcessFlow

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create custom control from the [Process Flow](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlow) control. This is what the base control looks like:

[image: ProcessFlow]

Now, I would like the ProcessFlow to have custom nodes wherein there will be buttons on each node, like so:

[image: ProcessFlow with custom ProcessFlowNodes]

So, the issue I am having is that since we'll have custom ProcessFlowNodes (pictured as square-looking notes), we will need a custom ProcessFlow control as the standard ProcessFlow only allows type `sap.suite.commons.ProcessFlowNode` controls under its `nodes` aggregation.

Thus, the hurdle is to create a custom ProcessFlow control with a custom aggregation that accepts the custom ProcessFlowNode control. My question in this regard is:

- Do I extend `sap.ui.core.Control` or `sap.suite.commons.ProcessFlow`? If it is Control, how does it know to be a ProcessFlow? My assumption here (I believe I am partly answering my own question) is that ProcessFlow is to be extended. Then, the next issue is the console errors such as "oControl must be an sap.ui.core.Control or empty" when I try to render the control with `oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("lanes"))`. **How can I resolve these errors?**

[image: console errors]

---

Here is a sample code with screenshot of how a basic, working ProcessFlow (namespace `xmlns="sap.suite.ui.commons"`) looks:

```xml
<ProcessFlow>
  <nodes>
    <ProcessFlowNode
      title="Sales Order Volume"
      titleAbbreviation="SOV1"
      laneId="0"
      nodeId="01"
      children="010,011"
      state="Positive"
      stateText="OK status"
      texts="Sales Order Document Overdue long text for the wrap up all the aspects - Not cleared"
      highlighted="false"
      focused="true"
    />
    <ProcessFlowNode
      title="Outbound Delivery 40"
      titleAbbreviation="OD40"
      laneId="0"
      nodeId="010"
      state="Negative"
      stateText="NOT OK"
      texts="Save Our Soul"
      highlighted="false"
      focused="false"
    />
    <!-- ... -->
  </nodes>
  <lanes>
    <ProcessFlowLaneHeader laneId="0" iconSrc="sap-icon://order-status" text="Order Processing" position="0" />
    <ProcessFlowLaneHeader laneId="1" iconSrc="sap-icon://monitor-payments" text="Delivery Processing" position="1" />
    <ProcessFlowLaneHeader laneId="2" iconSrc="sap-icon://payment-approval" text="Invoicing" position="2" />
    <ProcessFlowLaneHeader laneId="3" iconSrc="sap-icon://money-bills" text="Accounting" position="3" />
  </lanes>
</ProcessFlow>
```

[image: sample ProcessFlow code]

---

Here is my code thus far:

Control:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/suite/ui/commons/ProcessFlow"
], function(ProcessFlow){
  "use strict";

  return ProcessFlow.extend("ns.testino.control.SuperProcessFlow", {
    metadata: {
      aggregations:{
        "lanes":{
          type: "sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowLaneHeader",
          multiple: true,
          singularName: "lane"
        },
        "nodes": {
          type: "sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowNode",
          multiple: true,
          singularName: "node"
        }
      }
    },

    init: function() {
      
    },

    renderer: function(oRM,oControl) {
      oRM.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("lanes"));
    }
  });
});
```

View in the app:

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="ns.testino.controller.coke2"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:m="sap.m"
  xmlns="sap.suite.ui.commons"
  xmlns:custom="ns.testino.control"
>
  <m:Panel>
    <custom:SuperProcessFlow>
      <custom:lanes>
        <ProcessFlowLaneHeader laneId="0" iconSrc="sap-icon://order-status" text="Order Processing" position="0" />
        <ProcessFlowLaneHeader laneId="1" iconSrc="sap-icon://monitor-payments" text="Delivery Processing" position="1" />
        <ProcessFlowLaneHeader laneId="2" iconSrc="sap-icon://payment-approval" text="Invoicing" position="2" />
        <ProcessFlowLaneHeader laneId="3" iconSrc="sap-icon://money-bills" text="Accounting" position="3" />
      </custom:lanes>
    </custom:SuperProcessFlow>
  </m:Panel>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved the errors, by deleting the `init` method and having an empty `renderer` function.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/suite/ui/commons/ProcessFlow"
], function(ProcessFlow) {
  "use strict";

  return ProcessFlow.extend("ns.testino.control.CustomProcessFlow", {
    metadata: {
      // ...
    },

    // No init: function() {},

    renderer: {} // leave empty if you want it to render like the standard control

  });
});
```